# How to list all float columns in a Database with maximum decimal places?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to list all float columns in a database with the maximum decimal places. My end goal is to convert these float columns to decimal with the correct scal and precision.

I can list all float columns using the below

```
SELECT A.table_name, 
       column_name, 
       data_type 
FROM   DB1.information_schema.columns A 
       INNER JOIN DB1.information_schema.tables B 
               ON A.table_name = B.table_name 
WHERE  table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
       AND data_type = 'Float' 
ORDER  BY A.table_name
```

And see the maximum decimal place of a single float column like below

```
SELECT MAX
       (CASE Charindex('.', COLUMN1)
                    WHEN 0 THEN 0
                    ELSE
   Len (Cast(Cast(Reverse(CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), COLUMN1, 128)
                     ) AS FLOAT) AS BIGINT))
                  END) AS MAX_LENGTH
FROM   DB1.dbo.TABLE1
```

I am trying to combine the results of the two so I get the below.

```
table_name, 
column_name, 
data_type,
MAX_LENGTH
```

How do I dynamically get the results for all column in my second query and join it with the first query?

Thank you

Comment: Wbat do you mean by *"with the maximum decimal places"*? A `float`, as the name implies, using a floating decimal point. It's not like a `decimal` where you declare the scale **and** precision. Unless you mean, that if you have a `float(20)` that it's accurate to 7 digits, and a `float(50)` that's accurate to 15? But that isn't 15 decimal places.

Comment: parsename() will help with the splitting.

Comment: @Larnu - if we have 0.22 and 0.34567 in a float column, the max decimal place would 5 based on 0.34567.

Comment: the problem with float is that .22 is often referenced as .22000000000000000000001

Comment: I don't know a case where float should be used. Most of the time it is better to use the data type you expect like decimal, numeric or integer

Comment: There are benefits (and draw backs) to both `decimal` and `float` @KeithL. `int` is somewhat different in my mind, considering that you are specifically stating that all the numbers will be an integer value; so are aware you need to take into account things like integer math when introducing division, etc.

Comment: @KeithL - in .22 example, I would be wanting to return 2 as the max decimal place and am not concerned about 0.2200000000000000000001...

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do cannot be solved at all.
`Float` is not supposed to store **precise** values, for this purpose `decimal`/`numeric` types exists. `Float` is great for storing mega values that cannot fit in any "precise" type.

I give you an example. You can easily fit in float these values:

```
create table dbo.fl(col float);

insert into dbo.fl
values(2e100), (2e-100);
```

Any solution that you can invent will fail with these values.
The very concept of `float` is: it can store enormous values that CANNOT be stored in other types.

Comment: I am trying to convert float columns to decimals with the correct scale and precision based on how it shows in the table now. I know that 0.22 may be stored as 0.21999999999...... by the Database. All I need for now is what is the max precision i need to have for the decimal so data doesn't get truncated.